# where Custom module(custom HTML) save in localhost server folder in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.1

I want to know that, i am created website in local host and in it i create one custom module (or custom HTML), i want to find the location of that module in localhost folders. normally modules are save in C:\xampp\htdocs\shree\modules position in localhost folder but the custom module(custom HTML) location is not found.In this it uses another storage location of that, answer us.Thank you.

Comment: The data you insert into a custom module is stored in the database

Comment: Nothing you do in Joomla is saved in a folder for the most part. If you are doing it in the admin, it is almost certainly being saved in the database with very few exceptions.

Comment: It's odd but in fact it's stored in the content field of the module table.

Comment: Which table is it stored in the database? Please help!

Comment: @Eaint a quick and dirty way of finding out is using phpMyAdmin if you have it available. Put a unique term into a HTML module, and then search across all tables for that term in phpMyAdmin